# Rust plugin: Cannot implicitly convert type

Tags: c#

I have a message when trying to input a rust plugin. Started getting this after an update.  Unreleased plugin so I can't get support for it. any help would be greatly appreciated.

Error while compiling:

```
MyVehicles.cs error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type system.collections.generic.list<basevehicle.MountPointInfo> to BaseVehicle.MountPointInfo[]
```

Here is some lines:

```
1) using UnityEngine;
2) using System.Collections.Generic;
3) using Oxide.Core;
4) using Convert = System.Convert;
5) using System;
6) using System.Linq;
7) using Oxide.Game.Rust.Cui;
8) using Oxide.Core.Plugins;
```

lines 337-339:

```
337) var copter = ent as BaseVehicle;
338) BaseVehicle.MountPointInfo[] mountpoints = copter.mountPoints;
339) for(int i = 0; i < (int)mountpoints.Length; i++)
```

Comment: The [tag:Rust] tag is for the Rust language, not the game.

Comment: You need to do `BaseVehicle.MountPointInfo[] mountpoints = copter.mountPoints.ToArray();`

Comment: I'll give it a shot thank you!  It was working before the vehicles patch they did not long ago.

Answer (score 0):

Just change line `338` & `339` to be like this:

```
var mountpoints = copter.mountPoints;
for(int i = 0; i < mountpoints.Count; i++)
```